# Not making function call from event in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

In this when an event like `onMouseUp` happens in `getSingleCard` function rendered element I want to call the `expandDiv` function but the control is not going into the function nothing is happening. Can someone help me to fix this thing?

```
class  WikiArea extends Component
{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.expandDiv = this.expandDiv.bind(this);
    }


    render()
    {
      if(this.props.result!=null)
      console.log(this.props.result[1]);
      var totalArray = this.props.result;
      var y;
      var self = this;
      if(totalArray!=null)
      {
        return totalArray.map(this.getSingleCard,this);

      }
      else {
        return <div></div>;
      }
    }
    // onKeyPress ={event => this.onInputChange(event)
    //console.log(event.currentTarget.id);this.viewMore.bind(this, attributeId)

    getSingleCard(val)
      {
        console.log("syam");
        console.log(self);
        var x=val;
        if(val!=null){
        return (<div className="panel panel-default card-background" id={val["s.no"]}    onMouseUp = {event => {this.expandDiv.bind(this);}}>
          <p>{val["amt.pledged"]}</p>
          <p>{val.blurb}</p>
         </div>);
       }
       else{
         return (<div></div>);
       }
      }
    expandDiv(event){
      console.log("Entering into the div");
    }
};
```

Comment: You are mapping over totalArray in the render but you do not do anything with the mapped values. Try passing the mapped values into the getSingleCard method.

Comment: The array values will be automatically passed to the getSingleCard method be a map. We don't need to send that explicitly.The problem is that the component is rendered but the events like onclick or onMouseUp is not working since the control not going in to the "expandDiv" method